The div disappears from the DOM
when <div class="user-details-row"\> blocks appear, the <div id="usersPersonalDataContainer"\>\</div\> block disappears. usersPersonalDataContainer should be inside the userDetails block. It will display a status change message.
I am not very knowledgeable about frontend development;
I just want to add some visual appearance to my project, so please be understanding and, if possible, help and explain why this is happening.
Here are fragments of my script
function displayUsers(usersList) {
    console.log('Displaying users:', usersList);
    const usersInfo = document.getElementById('usersInfo');
    const usersContainer = document.getElementById('usersContainer');
    if ( !usersContainer || !usersInfo) {
        console.error('Element not found');
        return;
    }
    usersInfo.style.display = 'block';
    usersContainer.style.display = 'block';
    usersInfo.innerHTML = '';
    totalUsers = usersList.length;
    const startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * usersPerPage;
    const endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + usersPerPage, totalUsers);
    const usersToDisplay = usersList.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
    usersToDisplay.forEach(user => {
        usersInfo.innerHTML += `
            <li class="submenu-all-users-item">
                <div class="user-info">
                    <p>Phone: ${user.phoneNumber}</p>
                    <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="findUserByPhoneNumber(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')">Show details</button>
                </div>
            </li>
            <hr class="dashed-line">
        `;
    });
    updatePaginationControls();
}

function displayUserDetails(user) {
    const detailsElement = document.getElementById('userDetails');
    const currentPhoneNumberElement = document.getElementById('currentPhoneNumber');
    const currentEmailElement = document.getElementById('currentEmail');
    const currentBankCardElement = document.getElementById('currentBankCardNumber');
    const currentSubscription = document.getElementById('currentSubscription');
    const usersContainer = document.getElementById('usersContainer');
    if (!detailsElement) {
        console.error('Element with id "userDetails" not found');
        return;
    }
    function formatDate(date) {

        const options = {
            day: '2-digit',
            month: 'short',
            year: 'numeric',
            hour: '2-digit',
            minute: '2-digit',
            second: '2-digit'
        };
        return date.toLocaleString('en-GB', options);
    }
    const [year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond] = user.endTime;
    const date = new Date(year, month - 1, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond);
    const formattedEndTime = formatDate(date);

    detailsElement.style.display = 'block';
    detailsElement.innerHTML = `
<div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
    <p>Phone: ${user.phoneNumber}</p>
    <input id="newPhoneNumber" class="input-personal-data" placeholder="New phone number" type="number" required />
    <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="updateUsersPhoneNumber(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')"> Update </button>
  </div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
     <p>Subscription: ${user.subscription.subscriptionName}</p>
     <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="submitFindAlSubscriptions()" > Update </button>
  </div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
      <p>Auto-renew subscription: ${user.autoRenew}</p>
      <div class="auto-renew-options">
      <input name="Auto-renew" id="YES" type="radio" value="YES" onclick="updateUsersAutoRenewStatus(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')" checked />
      <label for="YES" class="users-personal-data-text">YES</label>
      <span class="radio-spacing"></span>
      <input name="Auto-renew" id="NO" type="radio" value="NO" onclick="updateUsersAutoRenewStatus(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')" />
      <label for="NO" class="users-personal-data-text">NO</label>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
    <p>Password: hidden</p>
    <input id="newPassword" class="input-personal-data" placeholder="New password" type="text" required />
    <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="updateUsersPassword(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')" > Update </button>
  </div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
     <p>Email: ${user.email}</p>
     <input id="newEmail" class="input-personal-data" placeholder="New email" type="text" required />
     <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="updateUsersEmail(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')" > Update </button>
  </div>
   <div class="user-details-row">
       <p>Bank card number: ${user.userBankCard.cardNumber}</p>
       <div class="bank-card-group">
           <input id="newBankCardNumber" class="input-bank-personal-data" placeholder="Bank card number" type="number" required>
           <div class="bank-card-details">
               <input id="newBankCardExpirationDate" class="input-bank-card-expiration-data" placeholder="Expiration date" type="text" required>
               <input id="newBankCardCVV" class="input-bank-card-cvv" placeholder="CVV" type="number" required>
           </div>
       </div>
       <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="updateUsersBankCard(event, '${user.phoneNumber}')">Update</button>
   </div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
     <p>Subscription end time: ${formattedEndTime}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="user-details-row">
     <p>Delete user: </p>
     <button class="submenu-all-users-button" onclick="deleteUserByPhoneNumber('${user.phoneNumber}')" > Delete </button>
  </div>
</div>
      `;
    if (currentPhoneNumberElement) {
        currentPhoneNumberElement.textContent = user.phoneNumber;
    }
    if (currentEmailElement) {
        currentEmailElement.textContent = user.email;
    }
    if (currentBankCardElement) {
        currentBankCardElement.textContent = user.userBankCard.cardNumber;
    }
    if (currentSubscription) {
        currentSubscription.textContent = user.subscription.subscriptionName;
    }
    function setRadioValue(name, value) {
        const radios = document.getElementsByName(name);
        radios.forEach(radio => {
            if (radio.value === value) {
                radio.checked = true;
            }
        });
    }
    setRadioValue('Auto-renew', user.autoRenew);

    if (currentSubscription) {
        currentSubscription.style.display = 'block';
        submitFindAlSubscriptions();
    }
    if (usersContainer) {
        usersContainer.style.display = 'none';
    }
}

function displayErrorMessageForPersonalDataUpdate(message) {
    const submenuPersonalData = document.getElementById('usersPersonalDataContainer');
    submenuPersonalData.classList.add('submenu-personal-data-error');
    submenuPersonalData.innerHTML = `
        <p class="display-error-message-for-personal-data-update">${message}</p>
    `;
}

function displayMessageForPersonalDataUpdate(message) {
    const submenuPersonalData = document.getElementById('usersPersonalDataContainer');
     submenuPersonalData.classList.add('submenu-personal-data-success');
    submenuPersonalData.innerHTML = `
        <p class="display-message-for-personal-data-update">${message}</p>
    `;
}

Here is a fragment of the HTML
<div id="usersContainer">
    <ul id="usersInfo"></ul>
    <div class="pagination-controls">
        <button class="pagination-button" id="prev-page" onclick="changePage(-1)" disabled>Previous</button>
        <span class="page-users-info" id="page-info">Page 1</span>
        <button class="pagination-button" id="next-page" onclick="changePage(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="userDetails" style="display: none;">
    <div id="usersPersonalDataContainer"></div>
    <div id="subscriptionInfo"></div>
</div>

and styles
#usersContainer {
  display: none;
  position: start;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 5px 10px;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 520px;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-right: 20px;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  background-color: #faf0e6;
}

#usersInfo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin: 20px;
}


#userDetails {
  margin-left: 20px;
  display: flex;
  right: 50px;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 15px;
  background-color: #faf0e6;
  box-shadow: 3px 6px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 750px;
  color: #8b008b;
}
.user-details-row {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#usersPersonalDataContainer {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 150%;
  min-width: 160px;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 25px;
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  width: 265px;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(153, 102, 255, 0);
}
.submenu-all-users-item {
  list-style-type: none;
  color: #8b008b;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dcdcdc;
}
.user-info {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

First screenshot: before the appearance of .user-details-row,

second screenshot: after the appearance of .user-details-row.

The same problem occurs with <div id="subscriptionInfo"\>\</div\>
Maybe someone can help or point me in the right direction.

You might find reading the site help section useful when it comes to asking a good question. To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a minimal reproducible example. Here's a question checklist you might find useful...
